# nominatim osm query string route

Tags: search, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have a query which work fine:
`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Sheffield&polygon_geojson=1&format=json`

I want to write another qurey to download polyline between two station like the sample bellow:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/134946

My question is: is anyone know how to modify the query string to get polyline between two station?
`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=<what should go here?>`